# Docker Postgres + Django: Pytest fails

Tags: python, django, postgresql, docker

Since I moved to Docker Postgres, my tests via pytest fail. I now identified as the problem my database connection.

How it works:
When I use [PostgreSQL 10](https://www.postgresql.org/download/macosx/) on my Mac it works smoothly. As database credentials in my settings.py I use:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': 'project',
        'USER': 'MyName',
        'PASSWORD': '',
        'HOST': '127.0.0.1',
        'PORT': '5432',
    }
}
```

How it fails: Since I moved to Docker + Postgres, I have to use different credentials to connect to my Docker Postgres:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': 'postgres',
        'USER': 'postgres',
        'HOST': 'db',
        'PORT': 5432,
    }
}
```

As I want to use Docker rather than PostgreSQL, but still want to be able to test, I wonder if you have any solution for my problem?

Here my console log output: https://pastebin.com/MZsccuGJ

My Dockerfile

```
# Pull base image
FROM python:3

# Set environment varibles
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

# Set work directory
RUN mkdir /code
WORKDIR /code

# Install dependencies
RUN pip install --upgrade pip
RUN pip install pipenv
COPY ./Pipfile /code/Pipfile
RUN pipenv install --deploy --system --skip-lock --dev

# Define ENTRYPOINT
COPY ./docker-entrypoint.sh /docker-entrypoint.sh
RUN chmod +x /docker-entrypoint.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["/docker-entrypoint.sh"]

# Copy project
COPY . /code/
```

Docker-Compose

```
version: '3'

services:
  db:
    image: postgres
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
  web:
    build: .
    env_file: .env
    volumes:
      - .:/code
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    depends_on:
      - db
    container_name: project
```

Comment: I can only see validation errors in that pastebin - nothing to do with the connection to the database not working...

Comment: I can't see your log output. Is it correct you are needing web container to talk to db?